# Try run midnight commander and get error /lib/libgpm.so.2: file too short

Tags: centos

today I installed Linux CentOS 7.2-1511.
After I loaded pack for install Midnignt Commander

**yum install mc**

Try to run MC. Result OK.

After I reboot OS.

Try to run MC and get error

**/usr/bin/mc: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/libgpm.so.2: file too short**

I try to erase and install MC.
Error continues to be.

Please Help to resolve this problem.

Comment: broken filesystem

Comment: Resolve - reinstall OS?

Comment: argh... fsck the fs, then reinstall `libgmp2`

Comment: how right reinstall libgmp2?